# TypeError: text.substr is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make a simple component in order to integrate a readmore function into it to reuse it in my application, but I'm having a problem that I don't understand. After several searches, I wonder if this is not a subtlety of NextJS? Anybody have an idea? Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ReadMore = ({ limit, children }) => {
  const text = children;

  const [isReadMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);

  const toggleBtn = () => {
    setReadMore((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isReadMore ? text : text.substr(0, limit)}
      <button onClick={toggleBtn}>
        {isReadMore ? 'Réduire' : '... en savoir +'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReadMore;



using readmore in a component
```

`````
              <ReadMore limit={200}>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur lorem,
                  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut lab lorem.
                  Ut enim ad minim veniam,Lorem ipsum dolor, sit
                  amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis
                  consectetur molestias provident perferendis
                  voluptates veniam accusantium, quibusdam quod,
                  dignissimos iusto, eum error itaque ab harum.
                  Illum sequi neque consequuntur fugit Lorem,
                  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                  elit. Distinctio consectetur sit dolores, beatae
                  error ipsum eos est quidem, soluta nobis,
                  perferendis voluptatum? Dolor similique minus
                  assumenda doloremque corrupti aliquam nulla.
                
                </p>
              </ReadMore>````
`````

Comment: Children is not a string but a react component. You can use a prop instead

Comment: `substr` method is available for a `string` type, but children is an object (component tree inside the opening and closing `< ReadMore>` tag. Can you post what are you passing between your `< ReadMore>` & `< /ReadMore>` tags?

Comment: Yes, this is right <ReadMore> & < /ReadMore>

Comment: ok i found the error it's because i was putting a p tag in my html. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding `text` as a prop and not using children since children is not a string (as [Akshit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7692076/akshit-mehra) pointed out).

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ReadMore = ({ limit, text }) => {
  const [isReadMore, setReadMore] = useState(false);

  const toggleBtn = () => {
    setReadMore((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {isReadMore ? text : text.substr(0, limit)}
      </p> 
      <button onClick={toggleBtn}>
        {isReadMore ? 'Réduire' : '... en savoir +'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReadMore;

// <ReadMore limit={200} text={text}>
```